# Playing audio using red5 media server

Tags: audio, stream, red5

I have installed `red5 media server` via windows OS. Demo application are running perfectly. My question is, i want to stream audio from red5 media server. So please help how to store audio in red5 and play from red5 to my custom player(Jplayer) using php

Answer (score 0):

JPlayer doesn't require Red5. You can just put your media in a folder that's accessible via the web and stream from there. If you feel you must use Red5 then follow their examples for the demo app - you can even use the sample folder they stream those from since it doesn't sound like you need any server-side code.